# How to calculate value using selected cells in R

Tags: r, function, loops, with-statement

I am trying to calculate inverse-distance weighted temperature values for selected sites based on projected temperature within 40 km radius to a given site. I have identified the projected locations and distances from each projected location to each site. I would be grateful if anyone could help me to do this in R because I have large number of files to do so and it consumes very long time to do this manually. My example data set looks like below.

```
+----------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Proj_Loc       | 2026_1 | 2026_2 | 2026_3 | 2026_4 | site_1 | site_2 | site_3 | site_4 | site_5       |
+----------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| P_129          | 24.46  | 25.2   | 26.54  | 28.49  | 39.96  |        |        |        |        |
| P_130          | 21.08  | 21.96  | 23.6   | 25.95  |        | 20.243 |        |        |        |
| P_131          | 25.2   | 25.99  | 27.2   | 29.07  |        | 17.679 |        |        |        |
| P_136          | 21.95  | 22.65  | 24.23  | 26.27  | 11.375 |        | 21.988 |        |        |
| P_137          | 16.02  | 16.92  | 19.08  | 21.8   | 24.922 | 29.99  | 17.613 | 34.637 | 33.041 |
+----------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

2026_1 to 2026_4 means the time resolution of my temperature data at each projected location given by the column Proj_Loc. site_1 to site_5 are my selected locations where I need to find the inverse-distance weighted temperature for the exactly same resolution as the projected data. The site_x columns indicate the distance from the projected location to a given site. I need to get my output as below.

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  site  | 2026_1 | 2026_2 | 2026_3 | 2026_4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| site_1 | 20.805 |        |        |        |
| site_2 |        |        |        |        |
| site_3 |        |        |        |        |
| site_4 |        |        |        |        |
| site_5 |        |        |        |        |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

The site_1 inverse distance weighted temperature for 2026-1 is calculated as; sum((24.46/39.96)+(21.95/11.375)+(16.02/24.992))/((1/39.96)+(1/11.375)+(1/24.922))

Anyone's help would be greatly appreciated. My example data set can be accessed using following dput.

```
dat= structure(list(Proj_Loc = structure(1:5, .Label = c("P_129", 
"P_130", "P_131", "P_136", "P_137"), class = "factor"), X2026_1 = c(24.46, 
21.08, 25.2, 21.95, 16.02), X2026_2 = c(25.2, 21.96, 25.99, 22.65, 
16.92), X2026_3 = c(26.54, 23.6, 27.2, 24.23, 19.08), X2026_4 = c(28.49, 
25.95, 29.07, 26.27, 21.8), site_1 = c(39.96, NA, NA, 11.375, 
24.922), site_2 = c(NA, 20.243, 17.679, NA, 29.99), site_3 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 21.988, 17.613), site_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 34.637), 
site_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 33.041)), .Names = c("Proj_Loc", 
"X2026_1", "X2026_2", "X2026_3", "X2026_4", "site_1", "site_2", 
"site_3", "site_4", "site_5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: What code have you tried yourself?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg this question is clearly lacking any attempt on the users part within R. I feel like it is still an okay question in this case, are you implying something?

Comment: @zacdav I'm implying that "what have you tried" is generally not a useful comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets get the two sub-dataframes Site distances and Temperatures at each resolution

```
dat0 = dat[2:5]
dat1= dat[6:10]
```

Do an inverse of Site Distance, since we are dealing with 1/distance values

```
dat1=1/dat1
```

Lets do a transpose of dat1

```
dat1=t(dat1)
```

Now, if you notice, the data frame that you want is just a matrix multiplication of dat1 and dat0 divided by the rowsums of dat1

```
dat1=data.matrix(dat1)
dat0=data.matrix(dat0)

dat1[is.na(dat1)] = 0
outputDat = (dat1 %*% dat0)/rowSums(dat1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reshape first, and then take weighted averages.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- gather(dat,key = sitename,value = siteval,site_1:site_5,na.rm = T)

df <- df %>%
    group_by(sitename) %>%
    summarize_each(funs(weighted.mean(.,siteval^-1,na.rm = T)),X2026_1:X2026_4)
```

Comment: I was stuck and thank you very much for all helps. All three answers work.

Answer (score 0):

```
a <- dat[2:5]
b <- dat[6:10]
outer(seq(ncol(b)), seq(ncol(a)), 
      Vectorize(function(i,j) sum(a[j]/b[i],na.rm=TRUE)/sum(1/b[i],na.rm=TRUE))
)
##          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
## [1,] 20.80583 21.56480 23.25761 25.46115
## [2,] 21.54172 22.38997 23.97984 26.22350
## [3,] 18.65744 19.46848 21.37052 23.78808
## [4,] 16.02000 16.92000 19.08000 21.80000
## [5,] 16.02000 16.92000 19.08000 21.80000
```